# Как открыть доступ в windows е для работ с прагмиро

Tags: windows

Здраствуйте как можно открыть доступ windows 32 system  ,я хочу открыть мою работу с демоне , и  из windows system 32 /drivers /etc там есть фаил hosts
Взял вставил на сабламм и последнее строке  написал 127.0.0.1" я моя работа " потом сохранял а там ошибка Error : отказано в доступе
(если  какие-то ошибки не обращайте, я новичок)

Answer (score 0):

Для редактирования файла hosts надо запускать редактор с правами администратора. Правой кнопкой по редактору и Запуск от администратора. Потом уже в самом редакторе открываешь нужный файл.

Comment: Я делал так вы сказали но те же ошибка,  но изменил на хост доступы и плюс добавил себе проблему в хосте были надписи какое-то прог после моеи ностроики на файле хост ничего нет как можно востонавить фаил хост, в ноутбуке востанновление фаил не настроен как можно другими способами, и как можно убрат все не доступы чтобы работать спокойно